# Mixing/dilution problem

Tags: calculus

> A tank initially holds $10$ gallons of fresh water. At $t=0$, a brine solution containing $\frac 12$ pound of salt per gallon is poured into the tank at a rate of $2$ gal/min, while the well stirred mixture leaves the tank at the same rate.
>
> $1)$ Find the amount and $2)$ the concentration of salt in the tank at any time, $t$

I have being able to differential equation by finding the values of rate in and rate out , my differential equation is DQ/DT + Q/5 = 1 . where Q is the amount of salt in the tank at time t

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have done quite a few steps, but I'm not able to upland pictures.

Comment: I have calculated the rate in and rate out , the I got the differentiation equation. DQ/DT + Q/5 = 1

Comment: What is $Q$ there?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Q, is the amount of salt in the tank at any time ,t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Q the amount of salt in the tank, then $Q'(t)=\text{difference of the amount of salt going in and out}$. Clearly, 1 pound of salt goes in per minute and $\frac{Q}{5}$ pounds of salt goes out.

Which gives the following separable ODE: $Q'(t)=1-\frac{Q}{5}$;
$\hspace{2pt}$$\frac{Q'(t)}{1-\frac{Q}{5}}=1$

Solving it yields: $Q(t) = c_1\cdot e^{\frac{-t}{5}} + 5$ Since $Q(0)=0$, the final solution is $Q(t) = -5 \cdot e^{\frac{-t}{5}} + 5$
And $C(t)=\frac{Q(t)}{10}=\frac{-1}{2} \cdot e^{\frac{-t}{5}} + \frac{1}{2}$